# Selecting all the Repositories in Artifactory

Tags: perl, artifactory

I have a requirement to give global read permission on all repositories in Artifactory through REST API and PERL scripting. For this I believe that I need to create a permission target with all the repository names listed [here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Security+Configuration+JSON) next to repository tag. But is there any special character or a path available using which I can select all the repositories at once? Or do I have to go fetch the repository names and embed them here in the required format?

Please help me out with this information guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always try and see for yourself, create a demo permission target containing all repositories in the UI and then call `GET artifactory/api/security/permissions/$permission_target_name` you will see it outputs:

```
"repositories": [
   "ANY"
],
```

There's also `ANY LOCAL` and `ANY REMOTE` respectively.

Calling `PUT artifactory/api/security/permissions/$permission_target_name` with the same [json](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Security+Configuration+JSON) will that you changed let you modify that target.

Comment: Thanks @fundeldman, I am able to access all the repositories now using "ANY" and "ANY LOCAL" the way you have mentioned.